numpy.where build conditional filter in python
How do I build a numpy filter, adding each filter element depending on logic, rather than initiating the entire filter at once?
I want to build a filter like this:
filter = []
IF A == 0:
   filter.append(np.where(a>0))
ELSE:
   filter.append(np.where(b>0))

As opposed to this.
filtered_values = np.where(
            (dataFrame['a'] > 0) &
            (dataFrame['b'] > 0))



where takes a boolean array, and returns a tuple of index arrays.

You can start with a filter of all True, then add the other conditions based on the value of A like so:
f = np.full(len(a), True)

if A == 0:
    f &= a > 0
else:
    f &= b > 0


I don't understand how this works but it does! Thanks.
